# highlight selected row in gridview and nothing else vb asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to be able to select a row from the Gridview which would be highlighted and that's it. I am able to do it with this code, but when I try to click another row instead (say the user selected the wrong row), it will crash giving me this error "Microsoft JScript runtime error: '__doPostBack' is undefined".

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        GridView.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub OnRowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Attributes("onclick") = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(GridView, "Select$" & e.Row.RowIndex)
        e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row."
    End If
End Sub



Protected Sub OnSelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles GridView.SelectedIndexChanged
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView.Rows
        If row.RowIndex = GridView.SelectedIndex Then
            row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.LightBlue
            row.ToolTip = String.Empty
        Else
            row.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
            row.ToolTip = "Click to select this row."
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to `RowDataBound` not being called again on postback.  If you inspect the Gridview via browser developer tools before and after you do the initial select I expect that, initially, the `onclick` event is properly set and disappears after the first select.

Databinding is tied to the cache and it may not be necessary to bind on every postback especially if you're only selecting a row.

you can either explicity call Databind() (not my first choice) or better, move the onclick generation to the RowCreated event which *is* called on every postback, or to the PreRender event where you generate the onclick by looping through the rows.

Comment: Thank you for the response, what would that look like as far as coding?